# Is there any way to run docker with multiple command?

Tags: docker

My command is here:

```
sudo docker run --name ws_was_con -itd --net=host -p 8022:8022 --restart always account_some/project_some:latest cd /project_directory && daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8022 project_some.asgi:application
```

but it returns:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I have to run with that command `cd /project_directory && daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8022 project_some.asgi:application` without CMD on Dockerfile

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `docker run ... sh -c 'cd /project_directory; daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8022 project_some.asgi:application'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide something to execute your command.

```
docker run <...> account_some/project_some:latest /bin/bash cd <path>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to run a command in a non-default directory, [`docker run` has a `-w` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) to specify the working directory; you don't need a `cd` command.

```sh
sudo docker run -d \
  --name ws_was_con \
  -p 8022:8022 \
  --restart always \
  -w /projectdirectory \  # <== add this line
  account_some/project_some:latest \
  daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8022 project_some.asgi:application
```

In practice, though, it's better to put these settings in your image's Dockerfile, so that you don't have to repeat them every time you run the application.

```sh
# in the Dockerfile
WORKDIR /projectdirectory
EXPOSE 8022 # technically does nothing but good practice anyways
CMD daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8022 project_some.asgi:application
```

```sh
sudo docker run -d --name ws_was_con -p 8022:8022 --restart always \
  account_some/project_some:latest
# without the -w option or a command override
```